# Extjs ajax request is returning in a disorderly manner

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

My application performs a code for query.
The user enters the 3947 code.

For each type a query in this case four querys.
But as the request is asynchronous, there is sometimes the last to arrive before others.
So it happens that the last record returned is 394 instead of 3947

How to ensure that the last appointment will come last?

```
listeners: {
    change: function (sender, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
        loadData();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your code. It will help us to understand better.

Comment: without any knowledge about your code, put these values in an array and then use a promisified call which goes throught that array

Comment: You should wait if user enters more keys before loading data from server. Or do you need the data for all the queries specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simplified way you could ignore all requests and perform only the last in this way:

```
listeners: {
    change: function (sender, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
        if (call_request) clearTimeout(call_request);       
        call_request = setTimeout(loadData, 750);
}}
```

Comment: That's what I needed something quick and simple, thanks!

Comment: That's the idea adis0099, fast and simple!

Answer (score 0):

Very simple with extjs, you can use buffers. For example, the following code will create a buffer interval of 500 milliseconds before you type new letter to wait for firing 'change' event. So, if you type fast enough, it wont fire change event until you finish. You can play with the amount of buffer as you wish

```
listeners: {
  change: {
     buffer: 500,
     fn: function (sender, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
         loadData();
     }
  }
```

EDIT: I read your post again, and i might be misunderstood. So i am giving solution for another case which might be your problem. If you are sending AJAX requests for each number typed, since it is async you cant know which will arrive when. But you certainly prevent that with some simple code change. You can use promises for example, this should work:

```
// lets define loadData (just an example)
var job = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     resolve();
});

var loadData = function(){
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          // do your job and when it finishes(can be async), call resolve
          // ...
          resolve();
     });
};

// listener
change: function(){
    job = job.then(function(){
        return loadData();
    });
}
```